# Check whether the given string satisfies WordPress password MD5 Format?

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption, woocommerce, md5

```
$md5 = "$P$Bb6HrFd7o8iTi/56mqsqco2.wpx.3D1";
preg_match('/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/', $md5) // failed
strlen($md5) == 34 && ctype_xdigit($md5) // failed
```

Tried above methods to check whether given string is WordPress password.

Is there any solution to check the given string is exact WordPress password format?

I need to check if the string is already a WordPress password then just create an user and update the user password without encrypting.

If the string is not a WordPress password format, then change it to a WordPress format.

How to know the string is a WordPress password here.

**This is for the purpose of importing users to WordPress - as CSV contains encrypted passwords from other sites as well as new text passwords for new users. So I desperately need a check to confirm if the password column string is an encrypted one or normal text string**

Comment: Above is always failed because there is diffrent algorithm as well DES or blowfish

Answer (score -1):

you can check if it a password with this:

```
<?php wp_check_password( $password, $hash, $user_id ) ?>
```

find more information here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password

Comment: I think this function is for checking the plaintext password against the encrypted Password. It has nothing to do with the question